# Aggregating multiple data types in pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a data frame with rows that are mostly translations of other rows e.g. an English row and an Arabic row. They share an identifier (location_shelfLocator) and I'm trying to merge the rows together based on the identifier match. In some columns the Arabic doesn't contain a translation, but the same English value (e.g. for the language column both records might have ['ger'] which becomes ['ger', 'ger']) so I would like to get rid of these duplicate values. This is my code:

```
df_merged = df_filled.groupby("location_shelfLocator").agg(
    lambda x: np.unique(x.tolist())
)
```

It works when the values being aggregated are the same type (e.g. when they are both strings or when they are both arrays). When one is a string and the other is an array, it doesn't work. I get this warning:

```
FutureWarning: ['subject_name_namePart'] did not aggregate successfully. If any error is raised this will raise in a future version of pandas. Drop these columns/ops to avoid this warning.
  df_merged = df_filled.groupby("location_shelfLocator").agg(lambda x: np.unique(x.tolist()))
```

and the offending column is removed from the final data frame. Any idea how I can combine these values and remove duplicates when they are both lists, both strings, or one of each?

Here is some sample data:

```
location_shelfLocator,language_languageTerm,subject_topic,accessCondition,subject_name_namePart
81055/vdc_100000000094.0x000093,ara,"['فلك، العرب', 'فلك، اليونان', 'فلك، العصور الوسطى', 'الكواكب']",المُلكية العامة,كلاوديوس بطلميوس (بطليمو)
81055/vdc_100000000094.0x000093,ara,"['Astronomy, Arab', 'Astronomy, Greek', 'Astronomy, Medieval', 'Constellations']",Public Domain,"['Claudius Ptolemaeus (Ptolemy)', ""'Abd al-Raḥmān ibn 'Umar Ṣūfī""]"
```

And expected output:

```
location_shelfLocator,language_languageTerm,subject_topic,accessCondition,subject_name_namePart
"[‘81055/vdc_100000000094.0x000093’] ",[‘ara’],"['فلك، العرب', 'فلك، اليونان', 'فلك، العصور الوسطى', ‘الكواكب’, 'Astronomy, Arab', 'Astronomy, Greek', 'Astronomy, Medieval', 'Constellations']","[‘المُلكية العامة’, ‘Public Domain’]","[‘كلاوديوس بطلميوس (بطليمو)’,’Claudius Ptolemaeus (Ptolemy)', ""'Abd al-Raḥmān ibn 'Umar Ṣūfī""]"
```

Comment: I get that the problem is that I cannot use np.unique() on a string and list `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'list'`. I just don't know another way to do what I need to do.

Comment: `df_filled.groupby("location_shelfLocator").agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())`?

Comment: @Emma that doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Please share your sample input data and expected result.

Comment: Sample data and expected output added above. The `subject_name_namePart` column is the one that is causing me problems. This could be done in two steps if that is easier e.g. step_one: make all cells lists of strings, step_two: `np.unique(x)`

Comment: your `subject_name_namePart` column's data has incompatible types. 1st row is string, 2nd row is array of string.  Do you have a control to fix the input data?  Also there is no `location_shelfLocator` in your sample data.

Comment: @Emma that is the problem I'm trying to solve. If the data types were compatible, my code above would work. I fixed the data above so it has the `location_shelfLocator` column.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot have a control over the input value, you need to fix it somehow.

Something like this. Here, I am converting string value in `subject_name_namePart` to array of string.

```py
from ast import literal_eval

mask = df.subject_name_namePart.str[0] != '['
df.loc[mask, 'subject_name_namePart'] = "['" + df.loc[mask, 'subject_name_namePart'] + "']"
df['subject_name_namePart'] = df.subject_name_namePart.transform(literal_eval)
```

Then, you can do (`explode`) + aggregation.

```py
df = df.explode('subject_name_namePart')
df = df.groupby('location_shelfLocator').agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks Emma, this line `df.loc[mask, 'subject_name_namePart'] = "['" + df.loc[mask, 'subject_name_namePart'] + "']"` is causing an error for me: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Comment: looks like `mask` is failing.  look the result of `df.loc[mask, 'subject_name_namePart']` and see what kind of data you get.  Here you supposed to have only pure string data. (string doesn't have brackets `[]`)